# Can I set up permissions per table in a database?

Tags: questdb

I'm trying to restrict the access to certain tables in a QuestDB instance, I would like to be able to have user-oriented permissions, possibly by type of operation like:

- `user1` has read access for tables `a`, `b` and `c`
- `user2` has read-write access to table `b`, read access to `c`
- `user3` has full admin to all tables

Is this kind of access control possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported yet, but there is an issue for this: https://github.com/questdb/questdb/issues/996

Or please start a discussion at https://github.com/questdb/questdb/discussions